# Instruments Memory Leak With ARC Confusion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

Good morning,

I was doing some fine tuning on this application I've been working on, just to make sure everything was running smooth and no memory leaks happened. So I ran my app with Instruments and I selected the allocations and leaks tool.

My app ran perfectly fine until Insturments detected a leaked object which happened to be a UIImage. What confused me was that I was using ARC so my understanding was that all retain/release/autorelease calls were being taken care of for me.

The other thing that confused me was, when I saw the Extended Details of the leak it showed that the Responsible Frame was [UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation] and I never called that method in my entire application, and I even did a search for it in my Workspace and got no results.

When I double clicked the leaked object to open it up in Xcode for me, it just opened up a frame and said "Unavailable". Screenshot below:

[image: Instruments screenshot]

And clicking on the Xcode logo to the right of it didn't help at all either. I've been trying to debug what this could possibly be and it has me stumped. I made sure NSZombieEnabled was set to YES just in case I tried to use a deallocated object, but I can't come to a solution. Why is this happening ( under ARC), and how can I fix it?

Thanks,

**EDIT:   This is the latest snapshot I have of the leak**
[image: This is the latest snapshot that I have for the leak]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the leak is then probably originating somewhere from inside the framework (UIKit or deeper). If so, then there's not much you can do about it. Either it's some sort of "side effect" from inside your application that shows up later and deep inside UIKit ([UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation]), or it's some problem with UIKit itself. But in the end it's hard to tell for sure!

Using ARC still doesn't guarantee 100% memory-leak free code! ;)

Comment: So if it is a problem with UIKit, then my app will be leaky when it ships? There wouldn't be much I could do about it?

Comment: Now the memory has expanded to something a little more complex, I took another snapshot

Comment: Unfortunately yes, so to speak! You/We can either hope that Apple fixes it with the next iOS release, or you could try to find a workaround so that your code doesn't execute the buggy framework code. How much memory is your app actually leaking right now?

Comment: Well it started with just 44 bytes, but with the latest snapshot I took, it got a little more complex ( still leaking code I haven't even written in this app) and now it's leaking around 380-400 bytes, which I guess isn't much, but it's still leaking

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**:

After spending my day debugging the code and wanting to ship it leak free despite the app  only leaking around 400 bytes, I got it leak free. Many thanks to @Nenad M for your help. It turns out a very strange source of my leak was setting my UITabBar's selectedImageTintColor to [UIColor blueColor]. This must have caused something deep inside CoreGraphics and/or UIKit to trigger the [UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation] call somewhere and not be released by ARC, just like you said.

Although this was a very small leak, I encourage all to ship your apps leak free!

Comment: Can I ask how you traced it down to something so obscure? Just a general plan of attack would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem then I change the code to use appearance selector like below then problem wen away

```
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
```